# zsh completion: complete --options for custom script

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have zsh completion rule for custom script. My script can take zero or more options (starting with `-`) and zero or more arbitrary strings (patterns):

```
_arguments -S : \
    '--foo' \
    '--bar' \
    '1:pattern:'
```

this rule works only partially, in following format:

```
script "somestring" <TAB>
```

offers `--foo` or `--bar` and `--f<TAB>` automatically completes `--foo`

However,

```
script <TAB>
```

does nothing, where I would like to have options listed (`--foo` , `--bar`)

and even when I explicitly start with `--` it shows the options but does not autocomplete them even when I am typing `--f<TAB>` and there is no ambiguity what option I want.

```
script --f<TAB>
```

should automatically completete `--foo`

So, to sum up, since `string` can be anything, there is nothing to autocomplete. Therefore, when I press , I want to autocomplete the --options, regardless whether i have alredy typed a string/pattern or not

I guess, I have to somehow specify in my completion rule that anything starting with `-` is an option, not string, and therefore should be auto completed from available options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something which works with me:

```bash
___script() { _arguments -S : }
__script() { _arguments -S : --foo --bar 1:pattern:___script }
compdef __script script
```

Comment: wow, thanks. I think this works exactly as I wanted. But I have no idea how this works. Could you please explain the logic, and what those many underscores mean?

Comment: assuming my script name is `h` is this the whole completion file correct? https://ctxt.io/2/AACQjj3-FA

Comment: Yes, it does. The `compdef` command does the binding of a command (`h`) and its completion script (`__h`)

Comment: With `__h`, and `___h`, you can use any name you want. But you have to be consistent and replace all occurences of `__h` (or `___h`) by what you want (but distinct names). The advantage of this notation is that it makes clear that `h`, `__h`, and `___h` are related. This makes them different which is required.

Comment: The syntax `1:pattern:___script` defines what should be completed as a first argument. The `___script` declare that options should be used. This makes the already declared options available. You may also have a `___h` which declares other options which would be added to the list for the first argument only.

Comment: note also that naming the completion function `script_completion` is not a good idea: when completing `scrip...` `zsh` would propose this function which is not intended to be called explicily.

Comment: and why do I need `compdef` twice?  `#compdef __h h` at the first line, and `compdef __h h` at the last line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145193/discussion-between-frederic-loyer-and-400-the-cat).